# How to create a grid-based website with an 100% width image?

Tags: html, css, grid

I want to create website based on the 1140 grid system with a "landing" image that fills the whole browser, so you'll have to scroll for the content. 
So, basically, when you open it, you see this image (with height and width that fill 100% percent of the browser, without any constraints) and when you scroll you see the rest of the page, which is in centered and in columns. 
Please not that I want the "landing" image to be scalable as well - it will fit an smartphone or tablet widts as well.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Aey6S/).  It is a very basic layout, but you should be able to get the idea from that fiddle.

Basically, you just create a `<div>` with 100% height and width.  It will take up whatever size the browser is, then you can add another block element below that to house your other content.

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/cats/1/0/c/i/3/iStock_AngryCat425x282.jpg"
                 style="height:100%;width:100%;"/>
</div>
<div>

    here is some other stuff</br>
    here is some other stuff</br>       

</div>​
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but some browsers, especially mobile browsers can stretch and pixelate/deform the image while using 100% width 100% height, whereas dependent on the image, you can use just 100% width and the height is automatically a perfect ratio to the original image as long as you have not previously specified a definite height

Comment: I hear you.  I totally agree about the mobile stuff.  I use that technique myself on mobile sites.  But the OP wanted to have it fill 100% of width and height.

Comment: I figured out this way but come on, there must be a more ellegant approach. What about if I make a div with the image and the just push the "container" with a margin-top?

Comment: http://danielfiller.com/ I want to achieve the same effect - the user is landing on the image, that fills the whole browser and then scrolls it (note that this giy used the 1140 grid)

Comment: if you'd rather assign special classes to the top `img` and `div` you could use this one instead  http://jsfiddle.net/Aey6S/2/   it's a bit cleaner code

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but honestly I want to copy this effect as in the danielfiller.com website - I am sure that the image is not stated in the HTML, but in the CSS there.. Any help? Cheers!

Comment: Actually it does work, neat! But the problem remains - I want to expand the image so it takes the full width of the browser.. I guess it should be out of the main container of the grid and still be scalable.

Comment: on the danielfiller site, they are defining the location of the image in here http://danielfiller.com/wp-content/themes/portfolio/style.css  line 227
"header.splash" element